# it's an attempt to... but tweak... , to fit -- I have a problem comprehending that

Tags: comprehension

Source: [*You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes*](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md)  by Kyle Simpson (2014)

Example:

> This mechanism is often called "prototypal inheritance" (we'll explore the code in detail shortly), which is commonly said to be the dynamic-language version of "classical inheritance". It's an attempt to piggy-back on the common understanding of what "inheritance" means in the class-oriented world, **but tweak (read: pave over) the understood semantics**, to fit dynamic scripting.

As I understand it, the part that begins with ***but tweak*** is just insertion text, kind of like a parenthetical statement. So, ***to fit dynamic scripting*** is the continuation of ***it's an attempt to piggy-back on the common understanding of what "inheritance" means in the class-oriented world*** (***to fit dynamic scripting***). What I have a problem with here is how exactly does that insertion text fit in with the rest of the sentence? What exactly do you think ***but tweak etc*** means? Is the author talking directly to me? Should I tweak the understood semantics? I don't fully grok the aspect it is used in.

Comment: Consider: "it's an attempt to decorate the house but keep the cost as low as possible".    More elegant than "but" would be **yet**.  "decorate ... yet keep".

Comment: CopperKettle: Sorry, my bad. I used the wrong link. I fixed it now.

Comment: TRomano: I guess that comma after the clause threw me off.

Comment: Punctuation marks are ants at the syntactical picnic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that "but-clause" in the sentence, Kyle is not addressing you, Cookie Monster, in a parenthetical manner. It's just part of the general flow of the sentence.

We can remodel the sentence a bit and the meaning will become clearer:

> This mechanism is often called "prototypal inheritance" (we'll explore the code in detail shortly), which is commonly said to be the dynamic-language version of "classical inheritance". It's an attempt to piggy-back on the common understanding of what "inheritance" means in the class-oriented world, **while tweaking** (read: paving over) the understood semantics **in order to** to fit dynamic scripting.

Comment: *prototypal* is just weird. I think it should be *prototypical*.

Comment: [I've found the original text](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md) and it's *prototypal* there. I don't feel a difference, although I also expected *prototypical*. There may be a difference.

Comment: The inheritance is based on prototypes, hence the use of the variant *prototypal*. It is the word commonly used when discussing javascript.

Comment: @CopperKettle I agree, I also thought "prototypal" a strange word. Perhaps he said "prototypal" rather than "prototypical" to indicate that he means related to the construct in the Java language that is called a prototype, rather than related to the general idea of a prototype.

Comment: Your version is a huge improvement on the original. The fact that it's still muddled is hardly your fault: it is the author's.